# How to decrypt a javascript file

Tags: javascript, obfuscation, virus, autorun, deobfuscation

I just discovered a virus in my computer that uses a .js file to attack. I opened the file in notepad to check out the code, but it is completely encrypted. I can see some data that makes sense (such as `bhynivmao.length!=4`), but the majority of the file is filled with gibberish.

There is also an autorun.inf and even though I can see some of the `shell \open\command`, I am not able to figure out the rest of the gibberish that is present.

Looks like both the autorun and the .js file are obfuscated the same way. Can someone please help me to get back the readable code? I am really curious to know how this thing works.

Comment: These hackers.. getting smarter and smarter.

Comment: Try posting the .js in pastebin and giving us the link.

Comment: share the js file so some of us can check it out

Comment: Thanks for the response.

Here is the pastebin link to the autorun.inf file

http://pastebin.ca/2376210

also the link for the gc2c9c.js file called by the autorun

http://pastebin.ca/2376212

and a third file(icece.js) i found on the computer. The other 2 were found in the USB stick.

http://pastebin.ca/2376213

Please take a look at it..

Answer (score 6):

Try using something like a JS beautifier:

http://jsbeautifier.org/

It will still keep the old variable names, but will definitely make the code more readable.

Comment: Thanks.
I will also try using JS beautifier and see what happens.

Comment: Wow.. It looks more readable now(Though i still haven't figured out what the code does). Looks like both icece.js and gc2c9c.js contain the same code. Here is the pastebin link for the beautified code.
http://pastebin.ca/2376219

Answer (score 4):

You might also consider using http://jsnice.org, which uses statistical analysis of code to identify variable names.  It complements http://jsbeautifier.org well by altering variable names but not structure.